# Is there any hashable built-in object is mutable in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashable

Curious about whether we can use hash() to check if an object is mutable or not?

Comment: What is the problem you're *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: See [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). Strictly speaking, it's possible. The requirement is that **any properties involved in equality are immutable**. Properties not involved in equality could be mutable. This is, however, *extremely* ill-advised. Why do you need to know if a particular object is mutable?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the bold sentence.

Comment: To what end? Why does it matter to you whether a given thing is mutable? That's not the problem you're trying to solve, that's how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from making a mutable object hashable. However the minute the data changes you won't be able to find the old copy unless you store all iterations of the old object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think how to satisfy his curiosity is the problem he wants to solve. Is it reasonable?

Comment: @HaochenWu it's not unreasonable, but it's *useful to mention*, and more or less completely pointless to speculate on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not pointless, if there is an object mutable while hashable, should we use it as a dict key?

Comment: @PythonNewHand no, I mean it's pointless for Haochen and me to speculate on what problem you're trying to solve. If that's what you're actually trying to find out, **put it into the question!**

Comment: That's one of the effect of this problem, I don't list it in the problem to make the problem simple and clearly direct, and this obeys the principle of this forum. You direct the topic to meaning of question, which I think is a little off topic.

Comment: @PythonNewHand It's true that jon is asking about a topic somewhat different than the question you posted, but that's not just okay, that's *good*. jon suspects that you have an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because the answer to the question you've asked doesn't have much practical use. Chances are the advice you *really* need is on the problem that led you to ask this question and that you'll get a much more useful answer by telling us what *that* problem is. In other words, give us some context so we know what information you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
>>> from collections.abc import Hashable
>>> mutable = [list, bytearray, set, dict]
>>> immutable = [int, float, complex, str, tuple, frozenset, bytes]
>>> all(isinstance(x(), Hashable) for x in immutable)
True
>>> any(isinstance(x(), Hashable) for x in mutable)
False
```

all mutable objects are unhashable.